# How can get current url with hashtag symbol in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to echo current url after ? with # symbol. But it isn't possible with php. So I have to do that with javascript. But I have no knowledge about javascript.
This is the url:

> https://example.com/r/?https://mega.nz/#!link!pass

I want to get after ? like:

> https://mega.nz/#!link!pass

And echo to screen with php.

I tried everything I've found but I didn't make it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageName = (function () {
var a = window.location.href,
b = a.lastIndexOf("#");
return a.substr(b + 1);
}());
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#element-id").html(pageName());
});
</script>
<?php
echo '<div id="element-id"></div>';
?>
```

I expect the output

> https://mega.nz/#!link!pass
>   But the actual output is empty.

Comment: That code for getting the hash fragment works for me. There's a much simpler way to do it, but that works for me.

Comment: Of topic question: is this url kinda Get url, should it have in that case some parameter name after ? -mark?Like "link=https://mega.nz/#!link!pass" ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, but he wrapped it inside $(document).ready()

Comment: https://site.pm/url={$url} I'm trying to set https://mega.nz/#link!pass section as $url. Everyone gave me the correct way. But I couldn't set as a variable.

Comment: @maximelian1986 - Doh! Thanks!  @ Baran - That code should work. Please update the question with a [mcve] (it has to be **in** the question, not linked, see [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)). When you've done that, please ping me in the comments (type @ and then pick my name from the list) and I'll reopen the question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the fragment portion of a URL, use its [`hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash) property:

```
var pageName = location.hash;
```

That will start with a `#` if there's any hash on the window (but will be `""` if there isn't). If you don't want the `#`, then

```
var pageName = location.hash;
if (pageName.startswith("#")) {
    pageName = pageName.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: When i posted this answer, I assumed the OP's code didn't work. But it does, it's just a different way to solve the problem. So...hmmm....

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href` to get the full URL - it works perfectly.

To get the hash (e.g. `#link`), use `window.location.hash`:

```
var pageName = window.location.hash;
```

Comment: Okay but how can I echo with php?